AudioHook emulator to Deepgram LiveClient transcription challenge
I have written an emulator for the Genesys AudioHook client in order to test my server-side implementation of handling AudioHook voice traffic.  The emulator uses PyAudio to record from the microphone and converts that audio into 8 bit mu-law b/c that is what AudioHook sends.  The emulator uses simple-websocket to send messages (both text and bytes are part of the AudioHook spec/api) to my server side.  Server uses flask_sock.  Server uses Deepgram LiveClient to send the raw bytes to Deepgram.  So, the server effectively just proxies the audio bytes.

The emulator and server received raw bytes are identical.  I can show this in any number of ways: By ponging them back to the emulator and letting it compare.  By having the bytes written to files on either end.  By plotting.  Etc.
If I send the raw data to Deepgram LiveClient directly from the emulator, it is transcribed perfectly.
If I use linear16, both emulator--to-Deepgrem and emulator-to-server-to-Deepgram are transcribed perfectly
If I send mu-law through the server, it is not transcribed.  Although it is transcribed by the emulator-to-Deepgram.  Why?  *** THIS IS THE CHALLENGE ***
I've verified that the LiveOptions and functions used are the same in both emulator and server.  And they they are set appropriately/identically for mu-law (or linear16 or whatever) in both places.

Deepgram can transcribe mu-law, 1 or 2 channels.  I've proved that exhaustively.  I can send linear16 through the system and it is fine.  And we have lots of setups using mpeg and opus sent from clients to our server and then to Deepgram.  But for some reason i can't proxy mulaw from my emulator, through my server, to Deepgram.  I get a "speech started" event and then nothing.
Anybody have any really off the wall ideas here?  On the one hand, I have been banging my head against a wall, trying to find some obviously goofy reason.  But, I'm starting to think it might be very obscure.
